# Show $A_{ab}$ are the components of a tensor.

Tags: tensors, general-relativity

The question asks: "If $v_a$ are the components of a vector, show that in an *arbitrary*  coordinate system that $A_{ab}$ are components of a rank-2 tensor, where:"

$$A_{ab}= \partial_bv_a-\partial_av_b $$

I've tried using the transformation law. However, when I expand the differentials using the chain rule and then change the $v_a$ into a new frame, I get a two second derivative terms that don't transform as a tensor. I cannot get rid of these and hence any help would be appreciated.

Do I need to use the connection somewhere in this transformation? So far I have not.

Thanks!

The 2nd derivative terms I get are:

$$ \frac{\partial x^c}{\partial x'^b}\frac{\partial^2x^d}{\partial x^c\partial x'^a} - \frac{\partial x^c}{\partial x'^a}\frac{\partial^2x^d}{\partial x^c\partial x'^b} $$

where c and d are dummy indices and a and b are free indices. Why do these two terms cancel?

Comment: Second derivative terms cancel because of equality of mixed partial derivatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule

$$\frac{\partial x^c}{\partial x'^b}\frac{\partial^2x^d}{\partial x^c\partial x'^a}=\frac{\partial^2x^d}{\partial x'^b\partial x'^a}$$

and similarly the other term becomes

$$\frac{\partial^2x^d}{\partial x'^a\partial x'^b}.$$

Then these terms cancel because, as ziggurism says in the comments, of "equality of mixed partial derivatives" i.e. the fact that

$$\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial u\;\partial v}=\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial v\;\partial u}$$
for arbitary $w(u,v)$.